# Call Method of one .ascx control to another .ascx control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 user control name as A.ascx, B.ascx and both of them are in single .aspx page.
I have one method let say Getdata() in A.ascx page.
How should I called that method in B.ascx.cs

I have tried some stuff on A.ascx page as

```
public partial class A : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{   
  public event EventHandler BindDataTotalSummary;

   public void BindDataTotalSummary()
  {
      //For example
      textbox1.Text = "";
      TaxesBreakdownRepeater.DataSource = dt;
      TaxesBreakdownRepeater.DataBind();
   }
}
```

**How should i call this method in B.ascx.cs page**

```
public partial class B : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ 
   public void MethodB()
  {
      A objectA= new A();//Showing error
      BindDataTotalSummary abc=new BindDataTotalSummary();//Showing error
     //Some Stuff of code
   }
}
```

Comment: your problem is little bit unclear. have you tried using object?

Comment: @KhairulIslam how to use ? I am trying calling directly page name of A.ascx or directly method name but its not helpful

Comment: have you tried by creating an object of the class in `A.ascx`?

Comment: I have to create object of which class?

Comment: @KhairulIslam please review my updated code, My code seems to be exactly like this, I addition what should i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your `BindDataTotalSummary()` method `static` then you will be able to call the method by using the class, like this way:

```
    public partial class A : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {   
      public event EventHandler BindDataTotalSummary;

       public static void BindDataTotalSummary()
      {
         //Some Stuff of code
       }
    }

   public partial class B : System.Web.UI.UserControl
   { 
     public static void MethodB()
     {
        A.BindDataTotalSummary();
        //Some Stuff of code
     }
   }
```

this shouldn't produce any error.

Comment: I can't, in that im binding Gridview, label , textbox and different controls, any other way to take care?

Comment: please review the code written in method BindDataTotalSummary()

Answer (score 0):

What about to create a `class` that contains `GetData()` method and call it from both `ascx` controls?

Your `GetDataClass`

```
public class GetDataClass {
     public void BindDataTotalSummary()
     {
          //Some Stuff of code
     }
}
```

First `ascx`

```
public partial class A : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{   
  public event EventHandler BindDataTotalSummary;

  public void MethodA()
  {
      GetDataClass objData = new GetDataClass();
      objData.BindDataTotalSummary();
   }
}
```

Second `ascx`

```
public partial class B : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ 
   public void MethodB()
  {
      GetDataClass objData = new GetDataClass();
      objData.BindDataTotalSummary();
  }
}
```

Comment: in  BindDataTotalSummary()  I need to call the server controls, we have to make a different class than how should we will call the server controls?

Comment: please review the code written in method BindDataTotalSummary()